# transformer waveform

Tags: transformer, oscilloscope

Can you see the output waveform of this transformer across it's terminals
if neither is tied to ground ? I assume it follows the input waveform in shape
but if there is no zero reference would it still be able to be seen on a scope?
Thanks[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE!  I need to mention though, that this looks like homework to me and that a lot of our experts will probably ignore it for that reason alone.  Is it?

Comment: Thanks. It's not homework. When I see a graph of an AC sinwave

Comment: Alright.  Just so you know, what made me think that was the (relatively) basic nature of the question with little to no supporting research or experimentation.  We like to see evidence that you've tried to solve the problem on your own and exhausted everything you can think of before asking.  That's more for your benefit than ours.

Comment: Also, if you believe the problem is solved, don't forget to accept the most useful answer, but wait a day or two to see what else comes up.  That gives both you and the answerer some reputation points, which are somewhat like currency here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, voltage is always across something.

Most scopes have grounded probes so the act of attaching the ground clip of the probe would ground the secondary, but if you use a battery powered scope or a scope with isolated probes you can measure the voltage accross the secondary without grounding it.

Between the output terminals you'll see basically an image of the input voltage scaled down by the transformer. if the output is not grounded the voltage from the secondary to ground will drift under the influence of capacitative coupling to the transformer primary, electrostactic charge, etc...